# Dependency Injection: all service methods receive the same newable object

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection

Lets take for example a class that projects and unprojects between 2D and 3D.

```
class Projector
{
    Point2D projectPoint(const Point3D& worldPoint) const;

    Point3D unProjectPoint(const Point2D& screenPoint, const Plane& plane) const;
};
```

Both methods need to use a Camera object. What would be the preferred way to implement it:

A. pass Camera in Projector constructor
B. pass Camera in each of the class methods.
C. pass Camera in a setter method before using the class methods.

Option A breaks DI because Camera is a newable. Option B means that the same Camera instance is passed in every call. In interfaces with 5-6 methods, passing the same instance to each method will result in less prettier code. Option C will work, however it means that the user of this class need to know that he should set Camera - there is a risk that he will forget to do this and will not understand why the code does not work.

What is the preferred way to implement it?

Comment: Look at it from the consumer's perspective (the code that calls `projectPoint`/`unProjectPoint`): do they have a camera instance to pass in? If so, then it sounds like option B would be the most explicit and readable. (I'm curious if you could clarify what you mean by "less prettier code", re: option B.)

Answer (score 1):

I would pass the camera in the constructor and have the camera and projector(s) that use it being instances within that scope. It sounds like the scope is defined by the 'point of view'.

Perhaps the camera is the point of view and the projector is a singleton of the camera?

By constructor is definitely, to me, the best. It may be a question of how you get the projector and/or camera. Your inferring a domain constraint, so code the constraint. May be the constraint is that a 'Point of view' has one camera and .... projector(s).

Comment: I am not sure i understand you answer. So you think Projector should get the Camera in the constructor? If no, than how the Camera is passed to the projector

Comment: It sounds like both the camera and projector belong to something. That your thing about 'how to' pass one into the other is very strong indicator. It is really and issue of identifying what they both belong to ... perhaps the both belong to 'point of view' or 'eyes'?